# Magento Upgrade error: Uri doesn't contain host part

Tags: magento, terminal, ubuntu-12.04

I am trying to upgrade from Magento 1.4.1 to the latest version using the following guide aon ubuntu 12.04 through terminal:

http://turnkeye.com/blog/magento-upgrade-guide/

however when I run a command through mage e.g.:

```
./mage list-upgrades
```

or

```
./mage upgrade-all --force
```

I get the error "Uri doesn't contain host part"

Could anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: How did you fix this? Im getting the same error but installing curl has not worked

Answer (score 4):

You're missing php5-curl.

On a ubuntu(or any debian based) system you would install that with:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-curl
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. I am still getting the same error. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your stack contains all required packages (php5, php5-curl, php5-mcrypt, php5-gd) if not then apt-get install them and restart your stack.

Comment: This didn't work for me. I am still getting the same error. Any other ideas?